# log4j:ERROR Failed to execute sql. Problem with mysql insert in appender

Tags: java, mysql, logging, log4j

I have a problem with log4j appender, that could log into database. There is my appender

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>

<appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
<param name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"/>
<param name="driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
<param name="user" value="root"/>
<param name="password" value="password"/>
<param name="sql" value="INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES('%x','%d','%C','%p','%m')"/>

<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"></layout>
</appender>

<logger name="log4j.rootLogger" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="DB"/>
</logger>

 <root>
 <priority value="TRACE"/>
 <appender-ref ref="DB"/>
 </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

There is my main class

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;


public class TestLogger
{
 /* Get actual class name to be printed on */
    public static final Logger log = 
    Logger.getLogger(TestLogger.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException,SQLException
    {
       log.debug("Debug");
       log.info("Info");
    }
    }
```

And im getting this error.

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'Debug' at line 1
 at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1393)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2353)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1303)
at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.execute(JDBCAppender.java:218)
at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.flushBuffer(JDBCAppender.java:289)
at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.append(JDBCAppender.java:186)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:260)
at TestLogger.main(TestLogger.java:13)
```

Whats wrong could be? i tried to insert into database with query in mysql workbench and it worked normal. I took this appender and main class here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm

Comment: Care to share your Log Table Configuration

Comment: CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `USER_ID` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATED` date NOT NULL,
  `LOGGER` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `LEVEL` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `MESSAGE` varchar(1000) NOT NULL
)

Comment: So, log4j.properties files with the same configuration works fine. 
But do anyone know what i need to do if i want to work with xml file? Could it be problem with quotes?